# Split screen more than twice button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a button that splits the screen when clicked. The button is on a html page called PF1.1.html and when the button is click i want it to spilt the screen but the new screen created to be a page named PF1.html and so on. No matter how many times u click the button it keeps creating split screen pages with the PF1.html.

This is the split screen test: https://jsfiddle.net/v1p5h9g7/1/

```css
/* Split the screen in half */

.split {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}


/* Control the left side */

.left {
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
}


/* Control the right side */

.right {
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
}


/* If you want the content centered horizontally and vertically */

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}


/* Style the image inside the centered container, if needed */

.centered img {
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="split left">
  <div class="centered">
    <h2>Don't know how to make it open PF1.HTML and how to resize it after</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="split right">
  <div class="centered">
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you not tried to do anything ?

Comment: I know how to split it in 2 but more than that i don't

Comment: At least show us the code you have for splitting into two

Comment: The code for split screen is now in the question i made @mplungjan

Comment: I made a snippet for you.

Comment: And what should it look like when you click second time? 4 panes?

Comment: It was supposed to add one more but if it is easier to make it 4 panes then let it be 4 panes

Comment: Also look into AJAX. For example use jQuery and `$(".centered").load("PF1.HTML")`

Comment: I don't know how to do it because i only learned javascript, css and html so where do i write what u said?

Comment: This is supposed to be a desktop look a like so when the person with the session opened clicks the button i want that to person to keep her session opened and where it was before clicking the button

Comment: So study and come back. It is not clear what you want and just splitting screens does not look like a desktop :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is, i think you want something like this - here is the code mentioned and also you can check out this

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Split screen on click</title>

     <!--added text to remove the answer-->
  <style>
  *{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  #container{
    width: 100%;
    /* height: auto; */
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
  }
  #child{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
  #clicker{
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
<button id='clicker' onclick="spliter()">Click me to create a new element</button>
<script>
function spliter(){
  var sec = document.createElement("DIV");
  sec.setAttribute("id", "child");
  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(sec);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```